# Openstack glance sync error

Tags: linux, cloud, openstack, openstack-glance

I am working on the OpenStack glance. after I entered the command

```
su -s /bin/sh -c "glance-manage db_sync" glance
```

beside the deprecated messages, I get lots of other errors that are relevant to python errors and `*Access denied for user 'glance'@'x.x.x.x'"*`error.

I have used the OpenStack document for Ubuntu step by step.
This is the source address: https://docs.openstack.org/glance/pike/install/install-ubuntu.html

How should I fix the permission error?

Comment: where is your glance and keystone installed?
if on the controller-node, then it might be because you have to configure MySQL/MariaDB configuration with a **bind-address** property.

Answer (score 1):

The error has to do with connecting to the DB with user 'glance'@'x.x.x.x'. See if you can access your DB (probably MySQL) with the same username + password that you have configured in Glance.

```
[database]
# ...
connection = mysql+pymysql://glance:GLANCE_DBPASS@controller/glance
```

Verify the user + password used in your connection settings.

If you are able to connect with the user + password then you need to look into your grants for the user. See which grants you have setup:

```
mysql> show grants;
```

Setup grants using a wildcard if you don't want to use specific IP addresses.

The older guides have the steps listed, while the newer guides do not:

https://docs.openstack.org/ocata/install-guide-ubuntu/glance-install.html

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON glance.* TO 'glance'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'GLANCE_DBPASS';
```

Comment: Most probably this can be the reason